# REGEX to get "any_characters((number,number))"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this type of string:

```
some text that can contains anything ((12.1,5.2))another text that can contains anything ((1,8.7)) and so on...
```

And in fact I don't know how to get :

> [0] some text that can contains anything ((12.1,5.2))
>
> [1] another text that can contains anything ((1,8.7))
>
> ...

I tried: `preg_match_all('#(.*\(\([0-9\.]+,[0-9\.]+\)\).*?)#',$lines,$match);` but for sure it doesn't work.
I also tried to add "U" option and ? after * and + but with no more results.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this variation on what you have:

```
 preg_match_all('#.*?\(\([0-9.]+,[0-9.]+\)\)#',$lines,$match);
```

The added question mark near the start is important , otherwise the dot will also consume the opening brackets. I also removed the part after the closing brackets, assuming your next line starts there.

Also you do not need the overall capture group.

The following

```
 if ($match !== false) {
      var_export ($match[0]);
 }
```

will output:

```
array (
  0 => 'some text that can contains anything ((12.1,5.2))',
  1 => 'another text that can contains anything ((1,8.7))',
)
```

Comment: I also had another problem because my text was multiline, I needed to add 's' option. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
/.*?\(\([\d.,]+\)\)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM5lH8/1)

Comment: This would match when there are more than 2 numbers inside the parentheses